# How to get true frequencies of Xeon cores in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, xeon

Does anyone know of a good way to find out what the actual frequencies are of the cores in my Xeon? I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I'd like to see if Turbo Boost is working properly, and it's also just nice to keep an eye on what's going on with the system.

Answer (score 1):

Does `cat /proc/cpuinfo` give you what you need?

Comment: I had great luck with 
<a href="http://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/lenb/acpi/utils/pmtools/turbostat/">Turbostat</a>

Answer (score 1):

Install the `cpufrequtils` package and run `cpufreq-info` for a list of the hardware supported frequencies as well as the % of time spent at each frequency.

However, it will not account for any "turbo" increases like what the Intel Atoms can do such as adjusting top frequency from 1.6 to 1.8 GHz (or even down to 1.4 in the reverse or power saving mode). The top freq will still be reported as 1.6 AFAIK.